# How do I capture the stdout and stderr of a call statemen

Tags: python

How do I capture the stdout and stderr of a call statement,I have the following command but I am not sure its is successful or not?can anyone provide inputs?

```
call("export COMMANDER_SERVER=commander.company.com" ,shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pretty much any method in `subprocess` but need to attach pipes. A simple way is in the docs:

```
 >>> subprocess.check_output(
...     "ls non_existent_file; exit 0",
...     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
...     shell=True)
'ls: non_existent_file: No such file or directory\n'
```

The docs also say the following about `subprocess.call`:

> **Note**
>
> Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function as that can deadlock based on the child process output volume. Use Popen with the communicate() method when you need pipes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to create a Popen object. For example:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
proc = Popen('command arg --option', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
return_code = proc.wait()
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
print(stdout if return_code==0 else stderr)
```

You can find out more about Popen objects in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).